# Basic LCD drive question for Lumex

Tags: arduino, lcd

Sure this is a pretty basic question for you guys, but figured I'd start here.  Is the linked LCD screen driven by some type of driver, or do you just supply logic voltage to whatever pin you want to illuminate on the LCD?

https://www.farnell.com/cad/2244525.pdf

So for example, if this were ran off of an Arduino, is there a better way to control the massive amount of pins?  I know some of the Adafruit stuff has I2C and or SPI with library, but didn't see anything for this one.

Is the best way to do that to use an array for each position of the digit in order to illuminate?  For example, if a rotary encoder were used just as a counter, each susequent counter step would be an array to supply voltage to the proper LCD lines?  Maybe this could be done more simply with bit shifting?  Just looking for any direction that someone may know.

Comment: LCD screens should be driven by AC voltage to avoid damage. Otherwise, yes, I *believe* you can just apply AC voltage to whichever pins you want to light up, since this display is not multiplexed.

Comment: (someone who's more familiar with LCD screens might be able to elaborate on that and write a proper answer)

Comment: you need a control chip if you want to use this with something like an arduino

Comment: LCDs require multiple level voltages to be applied across any single segment at different times ... the reason is that an LCD segment cannot have a net DC voltage level applied across it, otherwise damage occurs ... simplistically said, in any given second, any positive voltage across the segment must be offset by applying a negative voltage of equal duration

Comment: Thanks all.  Is there a DC equivalent of this type of LCD screen?  I know of the adafruit styles / varieties ... but this one is dirt cheap.

Comment: @jsotola Thanks. Will this require a specifc driver module or do "universal" ones exist that would allow me to interface with an arduino?

Comment: It is dirt cheap because it's just a bare-bones LCD. You'll have to research and develop your own driver circuitry to use it.

Comment: `this one is dirt cheap` ... no, it is not ... support circuitry is required to make it work

Comment: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00000658B.pdf shows how these LCDs work, and shows a matrix method of driving segments. Matrix method is complicated, but reduces # of drive lines from nearly 30 to something much less - perhaps few enough for an Arduino.

Comment: "Is there a DC equivalent of this type of LCD screen?": No, *all* LCD screens need AC control. You'll want something that is more than just the bare LCD screen, but includes control circuitry. That is exactly what makes the price difference. There's a few microcontrollers that integrate LCD control circuitry, but I don't think any of the (many!) different Arduinos do.

Comment: @rdtsc 10-4, thanks.

Comment: @glen_geek Thank you, seems like the limitation now may be the AC/DC thing from other responses.

Comment: @jsotola Looking for a display, that isn't the OLED adafruit style.  I wanted it to look more "industrial" using these LCD styles.  I wanted a programmable LCD that I can read output to the user on, in my case, it is so that they can set time to run for a watering system.  I'm not a fan of the 16 x 2 matrix style display with I2C backpack either.  So something different and "cheaper" was the main driver here :).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Lesson learned.  Thank you.

Comment: Jeremy - that matrix method accommodates the alternating requirement. You can set the alternating frequency fairly low (a few Hz to 10's of Hz). It needn't be kHz.

Comment: @glen_geek Ok, let me read it thoroughly tonight.  AT work now :)

Comment: this may help ... EEVblog ... https://youtu.be/ZYvxgl-9tNM

Comment: @glen_geek While I have a very basic understanding of port manipulation and registers, it looks like the data sheet is referencing use the PIC18F97J94 IC in order to control the LCD.  I didn't see anything about matrix control or what Hz to use.  This one might be out of scope for my current knowledge level, I'll likely just look for some OOB solution that is more readily adaptable for me.  Thanks!

Comment: this may help https://duckduckgo.com/?q=HT1621+LCD&ia=web

Comment: @jsotola Why yes, yes I think it does!  Thanks, looks like there are libraries for Arduino as well.  Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113829/discussion-on-question-by-jeremy-gardner-basic-lcd-drive-question-for-lumex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HT1621 LCD controller may work.

An arduino library exists for it.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=HT1621+LCD&ia=web

Answer (score 0):

> So for example, if this were ran off of an arduino, is there a better way to control the massive amount of pins?

Can't; you need a relatively specific control voltage, in an AC waveshape. Your Arduino simply hasn't got the hardware that makes that easy. ("many pins" means you'd need to literally switch a lot of pins at a relatively high rate, and that means Arduino-typical MCUs aren't the tool of choice – too few pins, too slow. Even if that weren't the case: you really want something specifically designed to drive LCDs, otherwise you'll just be burning power.)

You'll want a screen that includes that driver, or you want an external driver.

Comment: Actually it's regularly done with two I/Os in opposite phase.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yeah, I hit submit to quickly, see my edit from a couple of seconds ago - this is about the number of segments being hard to drive with an arduino of limited fanout.